# Print only selected elements/pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a page developed using C# MVC3. It's a multiple employees report. The generated page will have a check box for each record/employee. The idea is to let the user check the box next to each record they want to print. When they click the Print button, which is on the page, only those selected records will be printed. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to add/remove a class which will hide the content during print. Here is an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/XPFCQ/).

**Edit:** For maximum support, include a separate stylesheet instead of using the media query.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/print.css" type="text/css" />
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="a" name="a"/> A |
<input type="checkbox" value="b" name="b"/> B |
<input type="checkbox" value="c" name="c"/> C

<div id="a" class="no-print">Content A</div>
<div id="b" class="no-print">Content B</div>
<div id="c" class="no-print">Content C</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media print { 
    .no-print { display: none; }
}

/* For Styles */
div {
    background: #CCC;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.no-print {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#"+ $(this).attr('value')).removeClass('no-print');
    } else {
        $("#"+ $(this).attr('value')).addClass('no-print');
    }
});
```

Comment: thank u. I have pagination implemented on my page. So how to print the records selected across the pages

Comment: I am going to assume it is a Javascript pagination. Just use css to remove the pagination. Here is a nice tutorial on [print stylesheets](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/).

Comment: actually the pagination has been implemented in C# MVC

Comment: In that case, I would suggest either including all of them on the same page or submitting the form to the server and returning a "print" page.

Comment: I am using layout pages and containers. the pagination will be part of a container. Wondering, can i have  a  <div> in the layout page. As and when the user selects a record it will be added to the <div> in layout page and when the user clicks on the print button I can replace the <div> inside the container with the <div> from the layout page.